# how to change $allUsers = [] to array()?

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, while-loop, associative-array

The current code works on localhost as it uses PHP 5.4 but my live website uses PHP 5.3

Anyone how to change this so it will work on my live website?

```
$results = $dbc->query($sql);

$allUsers = [];

while($users = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $allUsers[] = [
        'userID' => $users['userID']
    ];
};

foreach ($allUsers as $user) {

    echo '$user['userID']'; 
}
```

The output is supposed to look like this:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

but it currently looks like this:

> 3

Comment: `PHP 4.3` --- oh shi.... The last 4.3 version was released in 2005

Comment: Perhaps (hopefully!) he means 5.3? 4.3 didn't support PDO, which is what I think he's using here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all PHP versions support this syntax, it better to stick to the traditional way:

```
$results = $dbc->query($sql);

$allUsers = array();

while($users = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $allUsers[] = $users;
}

foreach ($allUsers as $user) {
    echo $user['userID']; 
}
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you, I tried this: $allUsers = ('userID' => users['userID']); I was soo close

Answer (score 1):

```
$allUsers = [];
```

Is same as

```
$allUsers = array();
```

For older versions of PHP. But why on earth you would use PHP 4.3 on a live site in the 21st century ? :)

Oh your assignment within the loop also needs to change to older format

```
$allUsers[] = array(
    'userID' => $users['userID']
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, didn't test it,

```
$allUsers = array(); // Instead of []
```

documentation says that [] synax was implemented after 5.4.